# payumoney refund api in php

Tags: php, payumoney

In my mobile app, I have configured payumoney perfectly and its working great. Its just a case of refund. Below is the code in the php file which I call from the app:

```
include('../connection.php');

$orderid="AMD197";   

$view_rs =$conn->prepare("SELECT * from tbl_payumoney_order WHERE orderid=:orderid");       

$view_rs->execute(array(':orderid'=>$orderid));                 
$vfetch=$view_rs->fetch();

$merchantId="393463"; 
$paymentId= $vfetch['paymentId'];
$refundAmount= $vfetch['amount'];
$merchantAmount= $vfetch['amount'];
$aggregatorAmount= "0";
$refundType="1";

$data_string="paymentId=".$paymentId."&refundAmount=".$refundAmount."&refundType=".$refundType."&merchantId=".$merchantId."&merchantAmount=".$merchantAmount."&aggregatorAmount=".$aggregatorAmount; 

//paymentId=123456&refundAmount=56&refundType=1&merchantId=765433&merchantAmount=6&aggregatorAmount=50 


$ch = curl_init();      
$url = "https://test.payumoney.com/payment/refund/refundPayment";   

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  /* tell curl you want to post something*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string); /* define what you want to post*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); /* return the output in string format*/
$headers = array();

$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$output = curl_exec ($ch); 
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

$data = json_decode($output, true); 

print_r($data);

$status= $data['status']; 
$message= $data['message'];
$result= $data['result'];
```

I am getting this response:

> Array ( [status] => -1 [rows] => 0 [message] => Something went Wrong
>   guid 3k4pcbv6kdqf405g0lut7id32m sessionId null [result] => [guid] =>
>   3k4pcbv6kdqf405g0lut7id32m [sessionId] => null [errorCode] => )

Can anyone suggest if I am doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Refund API doesn't work in test/sandbox environment.

Please find the Refund API below for live environment:

https://www.payumoney.com/treasury/merchant/refundPayment?merchantKey=merchantkeyvalue&paymentId=1234&refundAmount=10

Please pass the Merchant Key, Payment ID and Amount in Params and Authorization Header in Headers.

Answer (score 0):

**Something went wrong...** error comes at PayUmoney's end due to 500, 502, 503 or 504
Server error in your App or Website according to [PayUmoney API Documentation](https://www.payumoney.com/pdf/API-Docs.pdf).

To know more about these HTTP Response Codes, you need to follow below link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Also update your Curl to get more info in case of malfunction like below:

```
$output = curl_exec($ch);

if ($output === false){
    // throw new Exception('Curl error: ' . curl_error($output));
    print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($output));
}
```

If you still not sure about your issue, then its better to contact [PayUmoney Support Team](https://www.payumoney.com/faq-dev-support.html).

Comment: Did the same way using PayUmoney API Documentation., no luck.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472935/how-do-i-integrate-payumoney-refund-api-in-php

Comment: 3) You also need to be able to add authorization to the header of the request:

Comment: Check my updated answer and update your Curl to get clear error message.